# React: can i use async in an onChange event function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

is it possible to use async to wait for a function to complete inside a onChange event.
Example:

```
const onChange = async (e) => {
   
      console.log(current[e.target.name]);   
      await setCurrent({ ...current, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      console.log(current[e.target.name]);
}
```

the second `console.log` is giving the same value since it is not waiting for the `setCurrent` to finish. Is there a way to make it wait for that?
Thank you

Comment: If your callback function will return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: "Is there a way to make it wait for that?" — Only if you make `setCurrent` return a promise.

Comment: `setCurrent ` is not Promise, so there is no point to use await for it. Are you using functional or class component?

Comment: I am using functional componenet and setCurrent is a useState Hook. 
i followed @ibraheem answer but got a warning stating callbacks cant be used with useState hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Put the callback to deal with the new state after its set in the second argument to setCurrent:

```
const onChange = (e) => {

  console.log(current[e.target.name]);   
  setCurrent({ ...current, [e.target.name]: e.target.value },
()=>{console.log(current[e.target.name]);}
);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When i do this i get the following warning:
State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect()..
Thats because setCurrent is updating a state using a useState Hook i assume.